# C dynamic data specifiers

Tags: c, arrays, integer, scanf

I want to write something like the following code, but I failed. 
I want to assign dynamic number of chars from array y to x. This number will be defined later. Here is a simple example of what I mean.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int x=0;
    char y[]={'5','4'};
    int z=1;
    sscanf(y,"%zi",&x);       
    printf("%i",x);         //Each time value of x=0
    sscanf(y,"%1i",&x);    //I want to make this 1 dynamic "int z"
    printf("%i",x);       //Here x value =54.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you working on a big-endian machine (e.g. a SPARC or PowerPC chip), by any chance?

Comment: I'm mechatronics student. studied pic16f877a  only .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Succinctly, you can't do what you want directly.

With `printf()`, you can use this, where all three variables are of type `int` and the widths will be read from `x` and `y`:

```
printf("%*.*d", x, y, z);
```

However, the `scanf()` family of functions provides nothing analogous.  A `*` means 'assignment suppression' in `scanf()`.  Note that in C99 and beyond, `%zi` tells `scanf()` that the type of the pointer argument is `size_t *`.  This probably accounts for why you got `0` as a result; `sscanf()` was writing out of bounds for the variable you passed to it.

Your best bet is to use `snprintf()` to create the format string you want used by `scanf()`.

```
int x;
char y[] = { '5', '4' };
int z = 1;
char format[16];
snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%di", z);
if (sscanf(y, format, &x) != 1)
    …handle error…
printf("%d\n", x);    // Will print 5
```

Note that if `z` is 1 or 2, this works OK; if `z` is larger, then `y` is not a null-terminated string and you run into undefined behaviour.  If `z` is zero or negative, you run into problems too.

Answer (score 1):

If you see , you declared and initialized array like this -

```
 char y[]={'5','4'};
```

`y` is not a string because it is not terminated using `'\0'` , so you need to explicitly add nul terminater . As `sscanf` will take a c-style string as first argument.

```
 char y[]={'5','4','\0'};   // or char y[]="54";
```

[Working demo](https://ideone.com/6ICpvl)